# Find single entries where there should be 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to find all the single entries in a table where there should only be double entries.

Eg.

| Unique_Key | ID | State_Sequence_ID | Localisation_Format_ID | File_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6644106 | 1315865 | 100 | 1 | 2064430-DNK.pac |
| 6644107 | 1315865 | 190 | 2 | 2064430.chk [DNK] |

I am looking to find all instances where the 2nd record does not exist.

The ID for each record will always be the same (although I do not know what that ID will be specifically)  and the Localisation Format ID will always be 1 and 2. I am looking to find all entries where Localisation Format ID 2 does not exist.

```
SELECT * 
WHERE ID has Localisation_Format_ID = 1 
but does not have Localisation_Format_ID = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple *not exists* criteria:

```
select *
from t
where not exists (
  select * from t t2 where t2.Id = t.Id and t2.Localisation_Format_ID = 2
);
```

Comment: I suggest to add `AND t.Localisation_Format_ID = 1` to the outer (main) query.